# Is there a software that can read a lot of document filetypes

Tags: pdf, document, epub, file-type

I know that, if you want to watch movies or videos, there is a program called VLC media player that lets you read many many media file types.
I am looking for something like this for document files (pdf, epub, ebook, doc, docx, rtf, html, txt, ... )

Thanks in advance if you know such a thing

Comment: Is there a reason Microsoft Word, LibreOffice writer, or something else along those lines won't work? That in combination with a web browser should cover most if not all of these (not too familiar with ebook or epub)

I mean, is there a reason you want ONE program to do all of these? Otherwise I would suggest getting several programs that each have their own specialty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) supports all of these formats.

I don't really know what you mean by the 'ebook' format, but Calibre can read EPUB, MOBI and AZW formats.